# jQuery - insert form into DOM, then bind events, then return to previous state

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to make an editable table for a tournament using jQuery and ajax.

The present table structure is as follows:

```
<table>
<tr id="result-243">
<td class="name">Somebody</td>
<td class="score_1">9.0</td>
<td class="score_2">7.0</td>
<td class="score_3">7.8</td>
<td class="score_4">9.9</td>
<td class="score_5">7.9</td>
<td class="edit-243"><div id="edit-243" class="edit">Edit</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What I want is to insert a form when the 'Edit' link is clicked.  This form would be populated with values from the current entry.  I can make this work as follows:

```
$('.edit').click(function() {
        result_id = $(this).attr('id').match(/[0-9]+/);
        sel = '#result-' + result_id;
        $.get(
            myScript.ajax_url, 
            {
                action:'getResults',
                id:result_id,
                nonce: myScript.nonce
            },
            function( response ) 
            {
                form = "<form id='save-" + result_id"' class='post-me'>";
                for(value in response) {
                    form += "<input type='text' name = '" + value + "' value = '" + response[value] + "' />";
                }
                form += "<input type='submit' id='save-this' name='save' value='Save' /></form>";
                $(sel).html(form);
            }
            );
    });;
```

I would obviously expect to be able to bind the form to a $.post() request, and that should post the data.  However, the problem I seem to be running into is as follows:

If I want to restore the previous table elements (as above) with new values, I can't click 'Edit' again.  I think it's because jQuery will bind events to DOM elements inserted on the fly, but only once.  I can't remove the elements without losing the event binding.

Any ideas for what's wrong with my design approach?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but please don't put click events on `<div>` elements like that: an `<a>` tag is better because it is accessible via the keyboard (unless you don't care about users who can't or don't use a mouse). Also, you seem to be setting your newly created form as a child of the `<tr>` element - really `<tr>` elements should only contain `<td>` (or `<th>`) elements as direct children and then your form should be in a `<td>` (so if you want the form to replace all of the current row you should try something like `<td colspan="6"><form>...</form></td>`).

Comment: point taken about the anchor...and I meant to wrap the form in a td element.  thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use ContentEditable instead (html5)? Then you can just wrap up the edited table and send the new values in once they are changed.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Ut8x/

```
<table contenteditable>
```

[Testing for ContentEditable support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882205/how-do-i-detect-support-for-contenteditable-via-javascript).

Thinking about your question some more and your existing framework - I think you can work around the event binding problem by either using `on` or not destroying old values until the form is actually submitted. Just hide the table row and replace with a form.

Then if the form is actually submitted destroy the old row. If user cancels out of submission then destroy the form and reshow the old row. Here is an example fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Ut8x/1/

```
$('.edit').click( function() {
    var $form = $('<tr><td><form><input type="text" /><button class="cancel">cancel</button><button class="submit">Submit</button></form></td></tr>');
    $(this).closest('tr').hide().after($form);
    return false;
});

//on cancel click show old row and remove the form row 
$('table').on('click', '.cancel', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').show().next('tr').remove();
});

//on submit click remove old row
$('table').on('click', '.submit', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: Sweet.  That's really helpful.  I was thinking I might have to put the form in the markup and hide it like you suggested, and your solution is tidy. Thanks.  Also, I didn't know about the contenteditable attribute!  I will definitely play with that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of jQuery you are using, try `on()` or `delegate()` instead of explicitly binding a click handler if you want to get around your binding problem.

```
// jQuery 1.7
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function() { ... });

// Previous versions
$(document).delegate('.edit', 'click', function() { ... });
```

jQuery docs for [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)(deprecated) with examples and links to `on()` and `delegate()`